# XAML/WPF Canvas or TextBlock Behavior Differences Between Windows Versions

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

The code below is used to view a thumbnail image of pages in a document.

```
<ListView x:Name="ThumbPanel" ItemsSource="{Binding OpenDocument.PageCollection}" SelectedIndex="{Binding PageIndexVM, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border MinHeight="50" MinWidth="50" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="5">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Image x:Name="ThumbImage" Width="{Binding ThumbWidth, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}">
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PageCached, Mode=OneWay}" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="Source">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource UriToImageWithRotation}" Mode="OneWay">
                                                    <Binding Path="CacheImagePath" />
                                                    <Binding Path="OriginalRotation" />
                                                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource viewModel}" Path="ThumbWidth" />
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PageCached, Mode=OneWay}" Value="false">
                                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource CheckGreen}"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0, 2, 18, 0">
                        <Image Width="16">
                            <Image.Style>
                                <Style>
                                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="{StaticResource CheckGreen}" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Value="False" Binding="{Binding IsSelected}">
                                            <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="{StaticResource CancelX}"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Image.Style>
                        </Image>
                    </Canvas>

                    <Canvas VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Canvas.Margin>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TextMarginConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
                                <Binding ElementName="ThumbPageNum" Path="ActualWidth" />
                                <Binding ElementName="ThumbPageNum" Path="ActualHeight" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                        </Canvas.Margin>
                        <Border x:Name="ThumbPageNum" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PageNumber, Mode=OneTime}" MinWidth="16" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="2" Background="White"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>               
</ListView>
```

In that code the last canvas is to display a page number notation in the bottom right corner of the thumbnail image.

The notation shows up and works fine, but I’m having a problem that occurs in Windows 7 when the thumbnail image is clicked and brought into focus; the TextBlock will disappear and a blank white canvas is shown. In Windows 10 there is no change to page number notation and it shows properly regardless of if the thumbnail image is clicked and in focus. I do not have a Windows 8 machine to test this issue.

I have been unable to figure out what is causing this issue or a workaround. If anyone has any insight in regards to what is causing this problem and/or a possible fix I would appreciate some help.

Below is an image of this behavior:

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by not explicitly setting the TextBlock Foreground property. When the ListView item was clicked it changed to a Selected Item and it's children adapted the Window Color and Appearance properties referenced at: "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Personalization\Window Color and Appearance\Advanced appearance settings...".

The font in my TextBlock turned white because that is my font color for a selected item in the Window Color and Appearance settings and it was not visible due to the white TextBlock background.

[image: Window Color and Appearance]